# Perforce streams, exclude files from merge/copy

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have following perforce streams structure: **main** branch and 2 development branches linked to it **dev_v1** and **dev_v2**. Both development streams has some build control files where version specific variables are located. Any change in these files will be reflected in Perforce Streams Graph and the system will ask me to merge them into main and then from main into other development branch.

How to exclude specific set of files in Perforce so that in case of any change the system will no show any difference between streams and will not ask to merge/copy them.

Answer (score 4):

If those build files should never be integrated you should set that path in the stream view to be 'isolate' instead of public. That will add the files to client views for that stream, but will exclude them from any generate branch maps. That will cause them to fall out of the integration calculation and Perforce will stop trying to integrate them.

Isolate was specifically put in streams to handle build files that are unique to each stream, so this is the perfect use.

Answer (score 0):

When you merge you can select which change lists you want to include in the merge, and which you want to exclude.  If you are using P4V when you get into the merge window you can choose which changelists to merge into the other code line.  Most of our items are set up as streams...if you are a using a standard depot the functionality to should be similar...if you have troubles let me know I can set up another depot on my dev server.

[image]

Comment: I have stream based depot. Yes this option will work. However there are ~15 change lists that should be ignored from merging. For these change lists, or let say specific files I want the perforce even not to show in stream graph to display green and red arrow showing the merge is pending.
As i understood it can be achieved with virtual streams where i can exclude unwanted files, but there should be other option to exclude them and use development and release streams.

Comment: So far as I know the only way to show them as not needing to be merged would be to revert the changes...I am not aware of a way to trick perforce into not seeing the changes needing to be merged/copied.

Comment: That would kind of defeat the purpose of source control...don't check  in the changes if they don't need to be there.