# How can I do a stream copy/merge of only a subdirectory in Perforce?

Tags: merge, perforce, perforce-stream

I'm using P4V. I work in a subdirectory (eg code/jorge) and other people work in another subdirectory (eg art/) that I never deal with. Additionally I have a stream where I do my personal work. Every so often I need to merge changes from the main line to my stream, and copy them back up. However, the files in art/ are large binaries and Perforce spends a long time thinking about them even though I've not touched them. Is there any way to have perforce merge/copy my directory (code/jorge) without it spending time trying to merge art/? Can I tell P4V to merge/copy only the code directory?

Related but not identical question: [Perforce streams, exclude files from merge/copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846133/perforce-streams-exclude-files-from-merge-copy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't touch those files, it might be easier to not include them in your stream at all rather than manually exclude them every time you do a merge.

I.e. if your stream Paths currently says:

```
share ...
```

maybe it should instead be:

```
share code/jorge/...
```

or, if you need the art for builds but never need to modify it, you might consider doing something like:

```
import art/...
share code/...
```

Comment: Actual config I ended up using: `share ...` `exclude art/`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the recommended option but you can actually merge without using the "Stream to Stream" option but the standard "Specify source and target file" options, even if you are in a stream depot.

So you can select any subdirectory as your source like 'dev/code/jorge' and the same subdirectory as destination like "main/code/jorge' and it will only consider that directory. We do it routinely in my team because we have a big mono repo and have not taken the time to setup multiple depots when we migrated to Perforce.